# Sintaxis de la funcion

Tags: python, funciones

No entiendo las sintaxis de las funciones en Python por mas que trato de entenderlas
Esta es una funcion para mostrar la tabla de multiplicar del numero que se introduzca en el input. Pero no entiendo porque a la funcion debo introducirle un parametro que no esta definido. Y porque en el resultado debo multiplicar el parametro por la sentencia que acompaña al for, segun mi logica deberia ser el numero que debo introducir en el input.

```
numero = int(input("Introduce un numero "))

def tabla_de_multiplicar(num):
    for number in range(1,11):
        resultado = num * number
        print("{} x {} = {}".format(num, number, (resultado)))
        
(tabla_de_multiplicar(numero))
```

Comment: Para ayudarte a pensarlo y no darte la respuesta masticada.. que parametro no esta definido que estas introduciendo en la funcion? si queres hacer una tabla de multiplicar, en general uno agarra y multiplica un numero X por 1, por 2, por 3.. o sea.. por lo que tiene number.. no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien tus preguntas:

1. Las funciones tienen parámetros para poder aplicar el mismo procedimiento con distintos valores de los mismos, en este caso, has definido en la cabecera de la función `def tabla_de_multiplicar(num):` un parámetro `num`, cuando llamas a la función en la última línea `tabla_de_multiplicar(numero)`, dentro de la función, el valor de `num` será el valor que hayas pasado como parámetro en la llamada, en este caso el valor de `numero`, que como has definido en la primera línea es `int(input("Introduce un numero "))`.
2. El `for number in range(1,11):` itera en los enteros del 1 al 10, en cada iteración, asignará a la variable `number` uno de estos valores en orden creciente, y ejecutará el cuerpo (contenido) del for para este valor. Por eso se multiplica `num` (que recordemos contiene el valor pasado por parámetro, osea el input) por `number` (que contiene el número de esa iteración).

Comment: muchas graciassss de verdad... esta es la explicacion que llevaba todo el dia buscando en internet